# Jms Broker connection - Test the connection before listening to the queue - java

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, messagebroker

We have a message listener that listens to the Queue configured. When the Message broker is stopped or down, the application exits abruptly. Is there way to check the JMS broker connection before listening to the queue. The listener code must be enabled only if the JMS Broker is up. We are getting the below exception when we listen to the Queue (with the JMS broker down)

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'xx'; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://xx:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
```

Comment: No. Listening to the queue tests the connection. Testing it again, before listening, is futile.

Answer (score 0):

you can not test your connection to be active, as whenever you setup connection with activemq it only succeeds if you have an activemq server running.

A good option can be to do it in Java code by handling 'connection exceptions' and trying to re-connect after specific intervals till no exception occurs.This will help in scenario where ActiveMQ is down before you try and setup connection with it.

Hope it helps,
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [failover transport](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) in your clients: `failover:(tcp://host:port?TCP_OPTIONS)?FAILOVER_OPTIONS`

When the connection isn't available (via the inner TCP transport), the failover transport will continue retrying until it is available and then establish the connection and let your client proceed as normal.  This will look like the client is hung, but it's just waiting for the broker to become available before continuing.  This configuration will also try to re-connect if the connection is broken for some reason (e.g. you restart your broker).

Most people use the failover transport to allow you to connect to whichever broker out of a group of N is available, but it's completely fine to use it with just one inner TCP transport; it will still try to reconnect periodically whenever it fails to connect to the single TCP transport.